# How to set up a reverse proxy to map dynamically URLs to TCP ports?

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

This is the use case: I have a server which will have Docker containers which will be created and destroyed on demand. The idea is be able to configure a reverse proxy and associate an URL with the Docker container's port.

```
Browser              <===>  Reverse Proxy  <===>  Docker server
http://proxy.cxx/id1                              http://server:9000
http://proxy.cxx/id2                              http://server:9015
http://proxy.cxx/id3                              http://server:9730
```

Of course, those associations are not static, and will change. I will update them in a memcache database.

In short, **is it possible to configure dynamically a reverse proxy and add/remove rules?** I have some experience with HAProxy, but I don't know if that is possible. I will appreciate your advice if you propose a different solution.

Comment: You mean something like jwilder/nginx-proxy? Why is that not suitable?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't know it... Let me try it before. Thanks!

Comment: In my case it's different servers as well.  e.g.:  `server1:9000`, `server2:9015`, `server3:9730`.  Did you intend to find an answer that can target multiple hosts?  Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik).

> Træfɪk can listen to your service registry/orchestrator API, and knows each time a microservice is added, removed, killed or upgraded, and can generate its configuration automatically. Routes to your services will be created instantly.

You can setup rules to forward traffic from domain/path to a docker container.

Comment: +1 Let me test it first before to accept this answer as the best one. Thanks!

Comment: I was surprised to see that this answer recommends a completely different proxy server (not HAProxy) as the solution.  The quesion is tagged HAProxy, so is it possible to do in HAProxy, do you have to use Traefik?